# Evaluate derivatives y'(0),z'(0),y''(0),z''(0) of implicit functions y(x) and z(x)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem

Evaluate derivatives $y'(0)$, $z'(0)$, $y''(0)$ ,$z''(0)$ of implicit functions $y(x)$ and $z(x)$, where $y(0)=-1$ and $z(0)=1$, given by system of equations: $x+y+z=0$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$

First step: I evaluated $y(x)$ as $x^2+xy+y^2=0$

But I have no idea how $y(0)$ can be equal to $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the implicit function theorem, you know that the functions $y$ and $z$ exist and are defined for $x\in(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ for some small enough $\epsilon$. You also know that for these functions, the following things hold (for all values of $x\in(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$:
$$x+y(x) +z(x) =0\\
x^2+(y(x))^2 + (z(x))^2 = 0\\
y(0)=-1\\
z(0)=1$$

Now, if I differentiate the first equation, I get that $$1 + y'(x) + z'(x) = 0,$$ and the second equation gives me $$2x + (y(x)^2)' + (z(x)^2)' = 0$$ for $x\in(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$. Of course, $(y(x)^2)'$ is simply $2y(x)y'(x)$. What happens if I take a look at the values at $x=0$? What equations do you get?

Comment: You are welcome. I suggest you really try to understand the concept behind my answer, as it is used very often.

Comment: One thing I do not understand is why what I tried to do before was wrong.      


How does this equation look like $x^2+xy(x)+y(x)^2=0$ when $x=0$? Wouldnt this be just $y(x)^2 = 0$

Comment: That's a good point actually. There is probably a mistake in your assignment, you should mention this to whoever gave it to you.

Comment: Are you sure there is a mistake there? Its an exam task from my mathematical analysis final.

Comment: eithere there is a mistake in the exam or there is a mistake in your rewriting of the exam. If $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$, you can conclude that $x=y=z=0$.